# Is there a way to add HTML inside a Rails partial argument?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, erb, partials

I have been trying to find something about embedding HTML code inside a partial argument for days but I have not found anything so I'm guessing it isn't possible. But it seems like it should be.

I have a static page in my Rails app which has a lot of sections and each section can have subsections. I could just make the entire page just plain HTML. But I didn't want to repeat the same formatting over and over in case I want to change classes or something else.

So I have the following _section.html.erb partial file:

```
<div class="row">
    <h4><%= heading %></h4>
    <% subsections.each do |section| %>
        <% if section[:header] %>
            <h5 class="primary-text"><%= section[:header] %></h5>
        <% end %>
        <p><%= section[:body] %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

That works fine. But what if I want to include a link to a page or an email inside one of the subsections? It doesn't work just by passing it in as part of the quotes text. It shows the actual HTML tags.

Is there a real way to do this or should I give up and just write plain HTML with repeated section formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mark your text as html_safe. For example:

```
<%= section[:header].html_safe %>
```

But I would suggest using sanitize method because of security resonons:

```
<%= sanitize section[:header] %>
```

Probably sometimes you will want to configure sanitize method. Here you can read how to do this: 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html

You can read more about security here: 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-scripting-xss

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for the quick answer and the additional documentation. I guess I just didn't quite have the right search words when I looked for the answer.